# Get Dropdown value in Product Page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-page

I want one dropdown value in Product view page in Magento 2. For e.g, if I have select custom dropdown value in the product from the admin section. Now I want this value in view page as an option to display.

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository');

$sizes = $productRepository->get('supply')->getOptions();
foreach ($sizes as $sizesOption) {
    if ($sizesOption->getValue() == '8') {
        echo    $sizesOption->getValue();
  echo  $sizesOption->getLabel();
}
```

}

But currently, they displayed all value in all product, not particular product value as per assing into products. I want this value filter by current product.

Comment: get attribute option ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following way to getting a selected dropdown text for product:

```
<?= $_product->getAttributeText("country_of_manufacture") ?>
```

Comment: It's Working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get product attribute option Id and option label using product object

**Get option label based on option id from product object**

```
$optionId = 10;

$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
   $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($optionId);
}
```

It will return option text ex. **Red**

**Get option id based on option label**

```
$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
   $option_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId("Red");
}
```

It will return option id ex. **10**

Use below code to check is attribute exist

```
$isAttributeExist = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode);
```

For more reference check this blog [Get attrubute (Rakesh jesadiya)](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-product-attributes-option-id-from-label-and-get-option-label-from-id-in-magento-2/)

I hope it works!

Comment: how can you get the dropdown option to choose, customer group tax on the product page? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302518/magento-2-customer-group-dropdown-tax-option-on-product-page

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 On Product Detail Page or on Product List Page you can get attribute with drop down value using following code:

```
  <?php 

    $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('delivery_times')->getOptions(); 
    echo '<select name="delivery-time">';
    echo '<option selected="selected">Delivery Time</option>';
    foreach ($attr as $attrDeliveryTimes) {
      if($attrDeliveryTimes->getLabel() > 0):
      echo'<option value="'.$attrDeliveryTimes->getLabel().'">'.$attrDeliveryTimes->getLabel().'</option>';
      //echo $attrDeliveryTimes->getValue();
      //echo $attrDeliveryTimes->getLabel();
      endif;
    }
    echo '</select>';   

?>
```

Comment: how to choose the dropdown option to tax prices including or excluding on product page.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302622/magento-2-3-x-allows-customers-to-choose-dropdown-option-to-tax-prices-includin